# Delete Folder containing script itself

Tags: bash, scripts, rm

Let's assume we have a folder `/home/user/testfolder`, and this folder contains several files, including an uninstall script. This script is supposed to delete `/home/user/testfolder` and all its content including itself.

I found snippets showing how to delete the script itself, but I didn't find one showing me how to delete the complete parent folder...
Of course this script should be able to work with any folder name (if the file is located in another directory it should delete that)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean including itself?

Comment: The script which is supposed to delete the folder is inside the folder

Comment: if it deletes itself, then how will it run? Include the links to these samples that you saw.

Comment: That's part of the question... I just want this script to delete all files I created with another script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within

Comment: You would have to copy the script to some other location, where it can be accessed while deleting the original file containing the script. This can be done in several ways, for example by copying it into the temporary directory `/tmp`. Please notice that it is a bad idea to delete directories and files that belong to the operating system. These are typically but not always owned by `root` (for example `/tmp`].

Comment: Edit: should be: ... (for example files in `/tmp`). Files and directories in `/tmp` will be deleted at shutdown and reboot.

Comment: I assume the deleting is the last thing the script should do?

Comment: @JacobVlijm correct

Comment: You can find the relative directory the script is called from by `DIR=$(dirname $0)` somewhere in your script, and then delete the whole directory by `rm -r $DIR`. This works, as you can delete a script even when it is running (as any executable as well). But you must not call the script from inside the directory; otherwise you get `directory busy` error.